# Infinite index subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Finite index subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ are well-know (at least we know that they are congruence subgroups).

But I wasn't able to find reference on infinite index subgroups.
Does someone knows how to find such a documentation ?

More precisely, I would like to know :
1) Does $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ has a infinite index normal subgroup ?
2) If no, what are, up to conjugacy, the infinite index subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ ?

Comment: I wonder why someone replaced the boldface $\mathbf{Z}$ by the blackboard $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: I rolled back the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding the trivial group, the answer to 1) is that there are none. This is because the center of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ is trivial combined with the Margulis normal subgroup theorem:

> Let $\Gamma$ be an irreducible lattice in a connected semi-simple Lie group $G$ with finite center and of real rank at least two. The normal subgroups of $\Gamma$ are contained in the center (hence finite) or have finite index.

I don't know if there is a substantially simpler proof of this fact for $\Gamma = SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ and  $G = SL(3,\mathbf{R})$ than specializing the proof of the general case --- I doubt that there is a way around proving that for a non-central normal subgroup the quotient $\Gamma/N$ is amenable and has property (T) and hence is finite. A nice exposition of the fundamental ideas leading to  Margulis's normal subgroup theorem can be found in [these notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/loeh/seminars/normal_subgroup_thm.pdf) by Clara Löh.

The resources available on the homepage of [Dave Morris](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/) (books/lecture notes/slides) could also be helpful.

I am pessimistic that there is a reasonable description of all infinite index subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$ up to conjugacy, since this includes in particular all subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Tits alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative) for a very coarse description of f.g. subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbf{Z})$.